# How to Aggregate percentages in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I want to add a total field to a table with percentages.

The `AVG()` Function within SSRS doesn't work for me because of the following reasons. ( The measures are in percentages)

```
 _______________________________
 |Group 1| Measure 1| Total 1   |
 |_______|__________|___________|
 |Group 2| Measure 2|           |
 |       | Measure 3|Total 2    |
 |_______|__________|___________|
 |Total  |__________|Grand Total|
```

> If Measure 1 is 100 %
> And Measure 2 is 0%
> And measure 3 is 100%
>
> Total 1 will be 100%
> Total 2 will be 50 %
> Grand Total will be 75% (100 +50 /2)
>
> While it should be 66% (100 + 100 + 0 /3)

The percentages are precalculated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calculating the average of the **Totals**, calculate the grand total of all **Measures**. So you should be able to use the `AVG()` function on all the measures of your datasource.

```
=AVG(Fields!Measure.Value)
```

This will basically calculate the total sum of all measure values and divide it by the amount of records that are in your datasource.

Comment: I used this expression in every single one of the totals

Comment: Yes, but you need to use this one for the grand total as well. Make sure its outside the group. When you calculate the average of the averages per group, you will get a different result then when you calculate the average of all the records. Which is what I am suggesting.

Comment: @KipDrordy, I think your issue is related to scoping. Try using `AVG(Fields!Measure.Value, "Group")` (replace `Group` for the name of your group) Totals, and `AVG(Fields!Measure.Value, "DataSetX")` for Grand Total (replace DataSetX for the actual name of your dataset).

Comment: @alejandrozuleta Thanks! I was unaware scoping works this way in SSRS.